# Jackson - Bean Properties from Nested Object

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON response which contains some standard fields and a nested object of `props` which contain sub class properties such as:

```
{
  "id":"whatever",
  "type":"Foo",
  "props":
  {
    "name":"My Name",
    "whatever":"Whatever"
  }
}
```

The fields `id` and `type` are standard and so I have a base class `Base` and then extend for some more specific class:

```
public class Base{
  private String id;
  private String type;
}

public class Foo extends Base{
  private String name;
  private String whatever;
}
```

How can I get Jackson to read the `props` object as the source for further field values? I assume I need to create a custom deserializer but I'm not sure how to accomplish this specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to deserialize `props` to an object property, you need to add a corresponding property to your `Foo` class.

E.g.:

```
public class Foo extends Base{
  private Bar props;
}

public class Bar {
  String name;
  String something;
  ...getters and setters...
}
```

Then you'll have access to the nested properties from your JSON via `bar.getName()` and `bar.getSomething()`.

Comment: This is actually what I am trying to avoid.  `props` is not an object on it's own, but a container for properties of `Foo`. Basically I want to flatten the response, telling Jackson that it should also use properties of `props` as the source for field values as well.

Answer (score 0):

Custom deserializer for Foo:

```
public class FooDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Foo> {

    @Override
    public Foo deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
        String id = node.get("id").asText();
        String type = node.get("type").asText();
        JsonNode props = node.get("props");
        String name = props.get("name").asText();
        String whatever = props.get("whatever").asText();

        return new Foo(id, type, name, whatever); //you need to create this constructor for Foo
    }
}
```

Main method example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String json = "{\n" +
                "  \"id\":\"whatever\",\n" +
                "  \"type\":\"Foo\",\n" +
                "  \"props\":\n" +
                "  {\n" +
                "    \"name\":\"My Name\",\n" +
                "    \"whatever\":\"Whatever\"\n" +
                "  }\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(Foo.class, new FooDeserializer());
        mapper.registerModule(module);

        Foo foo = mapper.readValue(json, Foo.class);
    }
```

Dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</dependency>
```